# JavaScript Change Text

Tags: javascript, html

Hello fellow coder i am new to web programming and i need so major help please :)

well basically what i want is that when a user clicks on a image it changes the text in the inner html. Now I want the text changing done by using javaScript but only using the if statement. What i mean is when we click on the image we can check the id and if we are clicking on the image change the inner text of the html

here is some code that i have managed to do :)

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Welcome to Test </title>
 <script language="Javascript">
        image1=new Image
        image1.src="picture1.jpg"
        image2=new Image
        image2.src="picture2.jpg"
    function Change(){
         document.getElementById("lol").innerHtml = "Hello world"
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body  style = " margin: 0px; padding:18px;">
   <table  align = "center" border = "1" width="500px"  >
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10" > <img src ="Logo.jpg" alt="This is the logo ">       </td>        <tr/> 
        <tr>  <td  colspan="10"  >   <tr/>    
        <tr> <td> <td/>  <td> <td/>  <td> <td/>  <td> <td/>  <td> <td/>        <tr/>    
        <tr><td> <td/>  <td> <td/>  <td> <td/>  <td> <td/>  <td> <td/>        <tr/>   
        <tr> <td> <td/>  <td> <td/>  <td> <td/>  <td> <td/>  <td> <td/>         <tr/>  
  </table>
  <object width="800" height="600" data="GreatMovie.wmv"></object>
  <img src = "buttonUp.jpg" alt =" click me " width = " 200" height ="300" border=0 name = "buttonOne"> 
  <a id="lol" href="#" onClick="Change();" onMouseOver="document.picture.src=image2.src" onMouseOut="document.picture.src=image1.src" > Hello
    <img name="picture" src="picture1.jpg" alt="My Image" />
    Hello
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the code work? It it doesn't, what have you do to make it work? Do you face an error/exception? Please explain what effort you've done so far and what do you face within your effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is innerHTML not innerHtml.

Here is a JSFIDDLE link: http://jsfiddle.net/ywPfK/

Answer (score 0):

You want innerHTML not innerHtml

Tutorial on it's use here: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php